# Bootstrap Switch :- don't want to apply on all checkbox

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i have one table in that i want to apply Bootstrap Switch on check-box and i am able to do that, but my problem is it is applying for all other checker where i don't want that.

my code is as follows :

```
    <div id="tableDiv">
  <table>
 <tr>
   <th>
       1st header
   </th>
   <th>
       2nd header
   </th>
   <th>
       enable 
   </th>
   <th>
      delete
   </th>
 </tr>
<tr>
   <th>
       1st data
   </th>
   <th>
       2nd data
   </th>
   <th>
       <input class="toggle" id="toggleCheck-1" type="checkbox"/> 
   </th>
   <th>
      <img scr="/img/delete.png" />
   </th>
 </tr>
<tr>
   <th>
       2 nd row data
   </th>
   <th>
      2 nd row data
   </th>
   <th>
       <input class="toggle" id="toggleCheck-2" type="checkbox"/> 
   </th>
   <th>
      <img scr="/img/delete.png" />
   </th>
 </tr>
<table>  
</div>
<div id="formDiv">

<form action="/saveForm" method="get">
  First Name : <input type="text" id="Fname">
  Last Name : <input type="text" id="Lname">
  Loging Name : <input type="text" id="loginName">
  Enable : <input type="checkbox" id="enable">
  age :   <input type="radio" id="above"> above 18
           <input type="radio" id="below"> below 18 
</form>
</div>
```

My DOM contains this 2 `<div>` on tab basis i have `show()` or `hide()` here in table i want to Bootstrap Switch[on/off] and i am able to achive that using

```
 $('.toggle').bootstrapSwitch();
```

but my problem is it get apply on `<div id="formDiv">` also which i don't want.

i have tried by id also

```
$('input[id^=toogleCheck]').bootstrapSwitch();
```

but still it is applying on `formdiv`.

i have refer this link http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/

Can anyone tell where i am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can use the not selector in jquery for that

```
$('.toggle:not(#formDiv)').bootstrapSwitch();
```

Comment: one doubt it is not enough to give class name ?

Comment: @SwapL you can give it like $('.toggle:not(#formDiv)').bootstrapSwitch();

Comment: ok so i have to give :not(#formDiv) ?? otherwise it will apply to all rt?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct!

I've just tried the same as you:

`$('.toggle').bootstrapSwitch();`

Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/nF2xQ/

Comment: Yes, here it is working i have shown this 2 div in tabs, while loading page it applying for all checkbox and radio of the body of DOM

Comment: Well, it seems like a problem with your table structure. 
Try to put `<td>` instead of `<th>` when you don't want a header.
I have updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nF2xQ/1/
Hope this helps

Comment: well i have used $('not wanted check box and radio id').bootstrapSwitch('destroy');

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('input[id="Fname"]').bootstrapSwitch('destroy', false, false);
$('input[id="Lname"]').bootstrapSwitch('destroy', false, false);
$('input[id="loginName"]').bootstrapSwitch('destroy', false, false);
$('input[id="enable"]').bootstrapSwitch('destroy', false, false);
$('input[id="above"]').bootstrapSwitch('destroy', false, false);
$('input[id="below"]').bootstrapSwitch('destroy', false, false);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!